# Difference between "picture" and "photo"

Tags: word-choice, nouns

When should I use one or the other?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A photo is a picture taken with a camera. A picture is any visual representation of a subject.

Comment: There was a confusion in my mind about the difference in both words.Thank you for making it clear here.

Comment: So, a painting could be a picture as well? Because it may a visual representation of a subject as well.

Comment: @Vadorequest: I suppose  a painting could be a type of picture, but we don't usually call it that.

Comment: What about the difference between a picture and an image? I don't see any difference anymore.

Comment: An image can refer to all of the above. It's a more general term. I suggest looking in a dictionary for specific nuances.